# Expected wait time for an event with increasing probability

Tags: probability

Let's say that we are waiting for an event to happen that has a probability of $i\cdot p$ of happening, where $i$ is the trial number and $p$ is a probability where $p^{-1}$ is always a positive integer.

In other words, the first trial ($i = 1$) has a probability of $p$ happening and the second one has a probability of $2p$ happening, etc… until the probability of the event happening reaches 1 for the trial.

What is a formula for the expected number of trials to wait until the event occurs?

Comment: So there is a moment when probability is greater than 1?

Comment: Let $~f(k)~$ denote the probability that the first $~(k-1)~$ trials fail, where $~f(1) = 1.~$  Let $~g(k)~$ denote the probability that the $~k$-th trial succeeds, where $~k \leq p,~$  Presumably, $~g(p) = 1.~$  Then, you want $$\sum_{k=1}^p k \times f(k) \times g(k).$$

Comment: @EgorIvanov I edited the question to make it more clear. Eventually the probability will reach 1 at which point the event must have happened so there will be no more trials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that the $k$-th trial occurs is

$$
\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(1-jp)\;,
$$

so the expected number of trials is

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\frac1p-1}\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(1-jp)\;.
$$

For small $p$, we can approximate this as

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\frac1p-1}\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(1-jp)
&=&
\sum_{k=1}^{\frac1p-1}\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\exp\log(1-jp)
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=1}^{\frac1p-1}\exp\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\log(1-jp)\right)
\\
&\approx&
\sum_{k=1}^{\frac1p-1}\exp\left(-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}jp\right)
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=1}^{\frac1p-1}\exp\left(-pk(k-1)/2\right)
\\
&\approx&
\int_0^\frac1p\exp\left(-pk^2/2\right)\mathrm dk
\\
&\approx&
\int_0^\infty\exp\left(-pk^2/2\right)\mathrm dk
\\
&=&
\sqrt{\frac\pi{2p}}\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

So you’d expect the number of trials to grow with the inverse square root of $p$. This is related to the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), where $p=\frac1{365}$ (disregarding leap years) and the $k$-th person to enter the room has probability $p(k-1)$ to share a birthday with someone already present.

Comment: The approximation gets bad when $jp$ is close to $1$, right?

Comment: @angryavian: I'm not sure which approximation you're referring to. Of the three individual approximation steps, only the first one contains $j$; if you're referring to that step: Yes, the approximation $\log(1-jp)\approx-jp$ becomes bad for $jp$ close to $1$. But if you were implying that this makes the overall approximation bad: That's not the case; the point (which perhaps I should have made explicit) is that the result self-consistently shows that the first approximation step is good for small $p$, since $j$ only goes up to the order of $p^{-1/2}$, so $jp$ is never close to $1$.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity; you've interpreted my concern correctly. Your argument seems a bit circular to me. You use a potentially bad approximation (since $jp$ can be as large as $1-2p$ in the first approximation) to conclude that the expected number of trials is $\propto p^{-1/2}$, and then use this [potentially inaccurate] result to claim that we can ignore the addends where $k \gg p^{-1/2}$? But maybe I am misinterpreting. Do you mind formalizing your argument in more detail? I appreciate your clarifications.

Comment: @angryavian: Self-consistent isn't the same as circular. In a self-consistent solution, you make an assumption about the solution, you find the solution based on that assumption, and then you check that the solution you found validates the assumption. In other scenarios, there might be unlikely cases with large contributions that can't be ignored, but here the badly approximated tail contributions are bounded above by $\frac1p$. It seems clear to me that that's enough; I don't feel like formalizing it but [if you insist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OVDKsaoSJ4)... ;-)